# Если на кнопку наползает другой слой, можно ли сделать её некликабельной?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-sdk

У меня есть кнопка `close` и `ScrollView`.

Когда кнопка находится в такой положении она должна быть кликабельной и видимой:
[как тут](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxPXA.png)

Когда на кнопку наползает RelativeLayout она должна становиться не кликабельной и не видимой:
[как тут](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSMmz.png)

Код:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="21dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1420dp"
                android:background="#99AAB5"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таком случае лучше использовать `NestedScrollView` в паре с `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="126dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/cyan"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <carbon.widget.RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <!-- content of AppBarLayout-->

        </carbon.widget.RelativeLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_behavior=
    "com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <!-- content of NestedScrollView -->

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Кликабельность и видимость кнопки можно задать в коде

```
R.id.close.isEnabled = false 
R.id.close.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
```

но лучше просто

```
R.id.close.visibility = View.GONE
```

Момент сближения или касания ScrollView к вашей кнопке можно получить в слушателе прокрутки.

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        // тут вам нужно сопоставить положение вашей прокрутки к положению кнопки
        
        int scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY(); 
        int btnBottom = R.id.close.bottom  
        
        if (scrollY > btnBottom) {
            R.id.close.visibility = View.Gone
        } else {
            R.id.close.visibility = View.Visible
     
    }
});
```

Comment: С видимостью проблема исправлена. Но когда кнопка видима, на неё всё ещё нельзя кликать. Но спасибо и на этом.

Comment: @Dewerro не забудьте вернуть isEnabled = true или поставьте вашу кнопку ниже scrollView в иерархии xml. Так же буду очень благодарен если вы отметите ответ как правильный

Comment: isEnabled = true не помогает. Если расположить кнопку ниже ScrollView, то она будет так же скроллиться, а она должна оставаться на месте, то есть должен создаваться эффект наплыва слоя на кнопку. Если хотите - могу сделать видео, как должно выглядеть. Ваш ответ отметить как правильный, я пока не могу, так как не решил проблему полностью.